# How can I use Javascript to play media on clicking an object?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I apologize for the basic question but I am new to programming and I cannot find the answer to my question in the tutorials I have. I have developed a HTML/CSS page for a project due in two days. I would like users to click an object on the page to access a presentation (which will play full screen). At the end of the presentation the user should be returned to my HTML page.

Can this be done using Javascript with HTML? If so, how?

Will I need to convert the presentations into mp4s?

Thanks, Amit.

Comment: A .`.pptx` presentation? If so, you can upload it to google drive and embed it with `<iframe>`, but unfortunately, I don't think you can force it to go full screen because of cross-domain issues but I may be wrong. See: https://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: thanks so much for your help! i was, unfortunately, unable to use it because of basic level of programming skills now. But i hope to improve soon and be able to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things, 
1.- you can convert the pptx to a mp4 an playit in fullscreen or 
2.- you can use a presentation js framework to help you with that (you will not use a fullscreen)

http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/13 here is the link to a presentation js framework =)
(this is the first one i click in google results but i guess you can get anothers, there are few of it)

Comment: thanks so much for your help, ernesto! i was, unfortunately, unable to use it because of basic level of programming skills now. But i hope to improve soon and be able to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I can not gess your code, but I think, what you are looking for is here:
http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type

http://jplayer.org/

Comment: thanks so much for your help! i was, unfortunately, unable to use it because of my basic level of programming skills now. But i hope to improve soon and be able to try this out.